# how to speedup google apps script api call xml for loop and sub for loop key value store

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

please could someone review and suggest avenues to explore to optimise and speedup. I am out of ideas. It is a function called from a google spreadsheet apps script and is a tad slow now there are over 200 jobs.

Any suggestions on faster constructs than the "for" loop? Or other brainy ideas for optimisation.  Is it the sub routine of parsing the tasks via a key value store ? Maybe there is a cleverer way to do this?

Interested to learn better approaches.

Many thanks if you can take a moment to help

*Example api response at the end

```
function updateTracker() {
  var output = [];

  // fetch and parse doc
  var document = xmlFetch('https://api.blahblah');

  //locate child set
  var jobset = document.getRootElement().getChild("Jobs").getChildren();

  //get api call status
  var WFMcallstatus = document.getRootElement().getChild("Status").getValue();
  if (WFMcallstatus != "OK") {  
    return "Call Failed"
  }

  //loop through jobs
  for (var i = 0; i < jobset.length; i++) {

    //job attrib from xml
    var jobstate= jobset[i].getChild("State").getValue();
    if (jobset[i].getChild("Type")) {
      var jobtype= jobset[i].getChild("Type").getValue();
    } else {
      var jobtype= "";
    }
    var jobid = jobset[i].getChild("ID").getValue();    
    var jobname = jobset[i].getChild("Name").getValue();
//    var jobdescription = jobset[i].getChild("Description").getValue();
    var jobclient = jobset[i].getChild("Client").getChild("Name").getValue();

    //array the wanted fields for our output row
    var jobrow = [jobstate, jobtype, jobname, jobclient];

    // subloop job tasks
    var taskelem = jobset[i].getChild("Tasks").getChildren();
    var tasks = parseTasks(taskelem);

    //prepare urls
    var intid = jobset[i].getChild("InternalID").getValue();
    var wfmurls = wfmUrls(intid, jobid);

    // concat arrays for saving   
    var jobrowconcat = wfmurls.concat(jobrow,tasks);

    //push to 2d array
    output.push(jobrowconcat);

  }
  return output
} 

//job task iterator
function parseTasks(taskelem) {


  //get a new keystore to find the element values of the custom fields from their id's
  var tknewob  = storedTkkeys()

  for (var j = 0; j < taskelem.length; j++) {
    //      var taskname = taskarray[j].getChild("Name").getValue();

    var taskid = taskelem[j].getChild("TaskID").getValue();

    if (taskid in tknewob) {
      var taskstate = taskelem[j].getChild("Completed").getValue();
      if (taskstate == "true") {
        taskstate = "✔";
      } else {
        taskstate = "X"; 
      }
      //using id and state we can build another ordered json
      var tkvalstr = ""+taskstate;
      tknewob[taskid].taskstate = tkvalstr;            
    }
  }
  // make a full row set with empty spaces to fill gaps
  var tkjobrow = [];
  for (var key in tknewob) {
    var obj = tknewob[key];
    var prop = "taskstate";
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      tkjobrow.push(obj[prop]);
    } else {
      tkjobrow.push("");
    }           
  }  
  return tkjobrow
}

// key store for tasks
function storedTkkeys() {
  //key values
  var taskkeystore = {2667746: { name: "(t1) Lead 1st Contact"},
                      2667747: { name: "(t2) Lead 1st Follow Up"},
                      2667753: { name: "(t3) Lead 2nd Follow Up" },
                      2667749: { name: "(t4) Quote Request"},
                      2667751: { name: "(t5) Quote Issued and Sent"},
                      2667754: { name: "(t6) Quote 1st Follow Up" },
                      2667755: { name: "(t7) Quote 2nd Follow Up"},
                      2667757: { name: "(t8) Contract Requested"},
                      2667759: { name: "(t9) Contract & Deposit Invoice Issued and Sent"},
                      2667762: { name: "(ta) Contract 1st Follow Up"},
                      2667766: { name: "(tb) Contract 2nd Follow Up"},
                      2677091: { name: "(tc) Contract signed"},
                      2677135: { name: "(td) Contract Confirmed"}, 
                      2667773: { name: "(te) Deposit Invoice 1st Follow Up"},
                      2667774: { name: "(tf) Deposit Invoice 2nd Follow Up"},
                      2684065: { name: "(tg) Deposit Invoice Paid"},                      
                      2667772: { name: "(th) Final Invoice Approved and Sent"},                                           
                      2667775: { name: "(ti) Final Invoice 1st Follow Up" },
                      2667776: { name: "(tj) Final Invoice 2nd Follow Up" }, 
                      2677121: { name: "(tk) Account Settled"}};
  return taskkeystore
}

<Response api-method="List">
<Status>OK</Status>
<Jobs>
<Job>
<ID></ID>
<Name></Name>
<Description></Description>
<Client>
<ID></ID>
<Name></Name>
</Client>
<ClientOrderNumber></ClientOrderNumber>
<State></State>
<Type></Type>
<StartDate></StartDate>
<DueDate></DueDate>
<CompletedDate></CompletedDate>
<InternalID></InternalID>
<Assigned/>
<Tasks>
<Task>
<ID>62028029</ID>
<Name>(t1) Lead 1st Contact</Name>
<TaskID>2667746</TaskID>
<Description>First contact with a lead</Description>
<Completed>true</Completed>
<Billable>false</Billable>
<Folder>1 Lead</Folder>
</Task>
<Task>
<ID>62028030</ID>
<Name>(t2) Lead 1st Follow Up</Name>
<TaskID>2667747</TaskID>
<Description/>
<Completed>true</Completed>
<Billable>false</Billable>
<Folder>1 Lead</Folder>
</Task>
```

Comment: be aware that usually asking "ways to to XXX" is usually flagged as too broad, hard to present a unified response.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.